# how to stream audio chunks using web audio API coming from web-socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, web-audio-api

I am streaming audio data in chunks through web-Socket from server

```
ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream("angular/data/google.mp3",
        {
            'flags': 'r',
            'highWaterMark': 128 * 1024
        }
    );
    readStream.on('data', function(data) {
        ws.send(data);
    });

    readStream.on('end', function() {
        ws.send('end');
    });

    readStream.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
});
```

on the client side

```
var chunks = [];
var context = new AudioContext();
var soundSource;

var ws = new WebSocket(url);
    ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

ws.onmessage = function(message) {
    if (message.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        chunks.push(message.data)
    } else {
        createSoundSource(chunks);
    }
};

function createSoundSource(audioData) {
    soundSource = context.createBufferSource();

    for (var i=0; i < audioData.length;i++) {
        context.decodeAudioData(audioData[i], function(soundBuffer){
            soundSource.buffer = soundBuffer;
            soundSource.connect(context.destination);
            soundSource.start(0);
        });
    }
}
```

But setting buffer `soundSource.buffer = soundBuffer;` for the second time causing an error

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'buffer' property on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': Cannot set buffer after it has been already been set

Any advice or insight into how best to `update` Web Audio API playback with new audio data would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you figure it out?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot reset a buffer on an `AudioBufferSourceNode` once it's been set. It's like fire-and-forget. Each time you want to play a different buffer, you have to create a new `AudioBufferSourceNode` to continue playback. Those are very lightweight nodes so don't worry about the performance even when creating tons of them.

To account for this, you can modify your `createSoundSource` function to simply create an `AudioBufferSourceNode` for each chunk inside the cycle body, like that:

```js
function createSoundSource(audioData) {
    for (var i=0; i < audioData.length;i++) {
        context.decodeAudioData(audioData[i], function(soundBuffer){
            var soundSource = context.createBufferSource();
            soundSource.buffer = soundBuffer;
            soundSource.connect(context.destination);
            soundSource.start(0);
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to keep the code style as close to original as possible, but it's 2020, and a function taking advantage of modern features could actually look like this:

```js
async function createSoundSource(audioData) {
  await Promise.all(
    audioData.map(async (chunk) => {
      const soundBuffer = await context.decodeAudioData(chunk);
      const soundSource = context.createBufferSource();
      soundSource.buffer = soundBuffer;
      soundSource.connect(context.destination);
      soundSource.start(0);
    })
  );
}
```

If you want to stop the old nodes as soon as new data arrives (it looks like you wanted that by resetting the `.buffer` but I'm not sure), you'll have to store them and call `disconnect` on all of them when it's time.

Answer (score 1):

Not positive, but I think you have to handle your streaming websocket buffer a bit differently. Maybe [websocket-streaming-audio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websockets-streaming-audio) package source code can give you better clues on how to handle your scenario.